# What can I use to generate a local XML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-builder

I have a project that I am working on and I do not know much about Rails or Ruby.

I need to generate an XML file from user input.
Can some direct me to any resource that can show me how to do this pretty quickly and easily?

Comment: There's not much to go on here, so I'll have to recommend in generalities. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309011/how-do-i-render-a-builder-template-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html) gem has a nice interface for creating XML from scratch. It's powerful while still easy to use. It's my preference:

```
require 'nokogiri'
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.products {
      xml.widget {
        xml.id_ "10"
        xml.name "Awesome widget"
      }
    }
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

Will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <products>
    <widget>
      <id>10</id>
      <name>Awesome widget</name>
    </widget>
  </products>
</root>
```

Also, [Ox](https://github.com/ohler55/ox) does this too. Here's a sample from the documenation:

```
require 'ox'

doc = Ox::Document.new(:version => '1.0')

top = Ox::Element.new('top')
top[:name] = 'sample'
doc << top

mid = Ox::Element.new('middle')
mid[:name] = 'second'
top << mid

bot = Ox::Element.new('bottom')
bot[:name] = 'third'
mid << bot

xml = Ox.dump(doc)

# xml =
# <top name="sample">
#   <middle name="second">
#     <bottom name="third"/>
#   </middle>
# </top>
```

Answer (score 6):

Nokogiri is a wrapper around libxml2.

Gemfile
gem 'nokogiri'
To generate xml simple use the Nokogiri XML Builder like this

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml| 
    xml.body do
        xml.node1 "some string"
        xml.node2 123
        xml.node3 do
            xml.node3_1 "another string"
        end
        xml.node4 "with attributes", :attribute => "some attribute"
        xml.selfclosing
    end
}.to_xml
```

The result will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
  <node1>some string</node1>
  <node2>123</node2>
  <node3>
    <node3_1>another string</node3_1>
  </node3>
  <node4 attribute="some attribute">with attributes</node4>
  <selfclosing/>
</body>
```

Source: http://www.jakobbeyer.de/xml-with-nokogiri